# PHP Error when trying to assign a product channel in Cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob, php-errors

Whenever I attempt to visit the Addons > Modules > Cartthrob > Products page after installing CT, I receive the following PHP errors: (http://cl.ly/image/2H0t162L2A2c).

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: channel_dd
Filename: views/product_channels.php
Line Number: 206
```

And

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: helpers/form_helper.php
Line Number: 324
```

This only happens when the default product channel doesn't exist. After creating the default channel I'm able to assign a new, custom product channel and delete the default.

I'm running EE 2.8.1 and CT 2.5.

Is this a known bug in Cartthrob, and is there a way to assign a product channel without first creating the default products channel?

Comment: Jon, do you have any other existing channels? It seems that you would need at least one for this page to display correctly. You could create a temporary/dummy channel and proceed as you were, then remove it later.

Comment: @SyA Nope, I intentionally didn't create the sample products channel because I didn't want/need to. It seems odd to require dummy content.

Answer (score 0):

So I know this question was posted a while back, but I arrived at it when I had the same problem and thought I would share my solution.

In exp_cartthrob_settings table in the database, find the rows with the key 'product_channels' and 'product_channel_fields', duplicate these rows and change the site_id and key values to match the site and channel field IDs.

This was useful for me when I was setting up my MSM second site. Also, I had created the new Products channel first in the MSM site so that I could get the channel field IDs.